# How Can I call all functions in class base views

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-class-based-views

I am new in django and used function based views till now. Now I started class base views but they are so confusing . like

```
class Newrecord(View):
    greeting="Hi" 
    def newPost(request):    
        deyCat = Category.objects.all() 
    def oldPost(request)
        deyold = OldCategory.objects.all() 


path('about/', Newrecord.as_view(greeting="G'day")),
```

Now How From class based url  I will access both functions ?  Or I have to implement logic in class when to execute which function ?  And How we can use them for inheritance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access by the http verb

```py
class SoveView(View):

    def get(self, request):    
        return #somestuff

    def post(self, request)
        return #somestuff
```

```py
path('about/' SomeView.as_view())
```

When visit `about/` with a get request `SomeView.get` will be executed.
When request with a post to `about/` `SomeView.post` will be executed.

In your case, I think, that you will need two differents classes because you
have two `get` endpoints, something like:

```py
class NewPosts(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return #somestuff

class OldPosts(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return #somestuff

path('newposts/', NewPosts.as_view()),
path('oldposts/', OldPosts.as_view()),
```

If `NewPosts` and `OldPosts` have some common behavior, you can create a
base class or some helper function

```py
class PostsMixin(View):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.username == 'fake':
         raise Exception()
        # do something


class NewPosts(PostsMixin):
    def get(self, request):
        super().get(request)
        return #somestuff

class OldPosts(PostsMixin):
    def get(self, request):
        super().get(request)
        return #somestuff

path('newposts/', NewPosts.as_view()),
path('oldposts/', OldPosts.as_view()),
```

Instead of a base class, a simple function will work too

```py
def common_stuff(request):
    if request.user.username == 'fake':
        raise Exception()
    # do something


class NewPosts(View):
    def get(self, request):
        common_stuff(request)
        return #somestuff

class OldPosts(View):
    def get(self, request):
        common_stuff(request)
        return #somestuff

path('newposts/', NewPosts.as_view()),
path('oldposts/', OldPosts.as_view()),
```

Another way can be using the same view but pass a parameter to that view

```py
class Posts(View):
    def get(self, request):
        type = request.GET.get('type', 'new') # get type query param, if is not present the default will be new
        if type == 'new': # /posts/?type=new
            result = Category.objects.all()
        elif type == 'old': #/posts/?type=old
            result = OldCategory.objects.all() 
        else:
            raise Http404() # just as example
        return #somestuff

path('posts/', NewPosts.as_view()),
```

```py
class Posts(View):
    def get(self, request, type):
        if type == 'new': # /posts/?type=new
            result = Category.objects.all()
        elif type == 'old': #/posts/?type=old
            result = OldCategory.objects.all() 
        else:
            raise Http404() # just as example
        return #somestuff

path('posts/<str:type>/', NewPosts.as_view()),
```

Comment: thanks for simple and good explanation .So If my function have diff functionality and are get type then I have to put them into two diff  class ? And this line super().get(request)  getting info from base class ?

Comment: Yes, if the methods have different functionality, you need two classes. Another option can use a parameter or query param and the same method

Comment: Thanks So much <3  I am feeling confident now :D thanks again